# Jupyter notebook could not open static file

Tags: python, macos, terminal, static, jupyter

I am learning to use Jupyter notebook. Before I didn't know that my anaconda already has Jupyter notebook installed. But when i used the "conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab" command to install it, it pushes back that "It cannot resolve environment successfully". Later I found that I already have jupyter notebook, so I just went ahead and launched it. However, this time the terminal shows a red line that says "[E 19:08:03.207 NotebookApp] Could not open static file '' and a few 404 warnings. I tried update my jupyter but it didn't work. Does some one have an idea of what may have caused this? Thanks!

Comment: Which command did you use to launch jupyter notebook?

Comment: I'd recommend you just reinstalling the whole thing from scratch, making sure you completely delete current anaconda installation.